# Ubuntu QGIS 2.4.0 SSL connection to remote PostGIS fails b/c can't specify certificates

Tags: qgis, postgis, ubuntu, ssl-error

I can connect with SSL in PGAdmin to my remote server, but it requires specifying the filepaths for certificate files due to my having different certs for different servers.

However, when connecting from QGIS, I cannot find the option to specify the certificates to use to connect to my remote host. So naturally, when I try connecting and require SSL I get

> SSL error: certificate verify failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After failing to find information online through searching, I decided to click on the HELP button in the PostGIS connection window. Here's what I saw.

[image: QGIS SSL Help]

After editing the file names to the required ones, the connection was a success. But the case of someone connection to multiple databases with... multiple certificates cannot be so rare.